# I'm Searching cryptocurrency exchange api

Tags: wallet, exchanges, api, currencies, market

We want complete cryptocurrency trading service from api requirement all api where we can integrate all services in my UI.
long story in short we want any service provider backend in our UI.

API

1. User Registration API
2. Login API
3. User Verification API
4. Document Verification
5. User Wallet
6. cryptocurrency buy sell api
7. Track all transaction
8. Realtime cryptocurrency price api
9. Comparison api

**Trading cryptocurrency:**

```
   1. BITCOİN (BTC)
   2.   ETHEREUM (ETH)
   3.   DASH COİN (DASH)
   4.   LİTECOİN (LTC)
   5.   ETHEREUM CLASSIC (ETC)
   6.   RİPPELE ( XRP)
   7.   BİTCOİN CASH ( BCH)
   8.   MONERO (XMR)
   9.   ZCASH (ZEC)
   10.  QTUM (QTUM)
   11.  BİTCOİN GOLD (BTG)
   12.  EOS (EOS)
   13.  ICON (ICX)
   14.  VCHAIN ( VEN)
   15.  TRON (TRX)
   16.  AELF (ELF)
   17.  MITHRIL(MITH)
   18.  MONACO (MCO)
   19.  OMİSEGO (OMG)
   20.  KYBER NETWORK (KNC)
   21.  GOLEM (GNT)
   22.  HSHARE (HSR)
   23.  STALLER (STL)
   24.  UNIVERSA (UNTP)
   25.  ADA (ADA)
   26. USDT
```

Please suggest any api provider who can work in turkey.

Answer (score 1):

1. [CCXT is a python/javascript library with the functionality](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) you request. You can then trade with any exchange you'd like such as Binance, Poloniex, etc.
2. [Gekko is a similar open source library for Node](https://gekko.wizb.it/) with similar functionality.

Comment: how i can get apiKey and secret key ?

Comment: @Gausul you get your api key and secret key from each exchange you'd like, such as Binance, then you use this within the code to control your wallet buying/selling of other currencies.

Comment: my question i want build Binance like website where my user can register login and do all activity like Binance over the any service provider api.

Comment: so you want to create an exchange?

Comment: Yes we want build exchange website like Binance

Comment: here are a few resources I was able to find on this topic:

http://merehead.com/blog/build-online-trading-exchange-platform-bitcoin-crypto-currencies/

https://www.quora.com/How-does-one-start-a-cryptocurrency-exchange

Comment: also you may want to look into decentralized exchanges (smart contracts)